# Am getting error trying to predict on a single image CNN pytorch

Tags: image, conv-neural-network, prediction, pytorch-dataloader

## Error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pred.py", line 134, in 
output = model(data)
Runtime Error: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [16, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [1, 32, 32] instead.

## Prediction code

```
normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.4914, 0.4824, 0.4467],
                                     std=[0.2471, 0.2435, 0.2616])
train_set = transforms.Compose([
                                 transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
                                 transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                 transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 normalize,
                                     ])

model = models.condensenet(args)
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
PATH = "results/savedir/save_models/checkpoint_001.pth.tar"

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH)['state_dict'])


device = torch.device("cpu")

model.eval()

image = Image.open("horse.jpg")
input = train_set(image)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        input,
        batch_size=1,shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
    
    #input_var = torch.autograd.Variable(data, volatile=True)
    #input_var = input_var.view(1, 3, 32,32)
    
    **output = model(data)
topk=(1,5)
maxk = max(topk)

_, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
```

[Am getting this error when am trying to predict on a single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R5FD.png)
[Image shape/size error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYxbw.png)

[Link to saved model](http://%5B2%5D:%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/11EsrtRjyxwCfV0rd_B6-P_oe0kfdWjK9/view?usp=sharing)

[Training code repository](https://github.com/ShichenLiu/CondenseNet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the for loop and train_loader, solved this by just passing the input directly into the model. like this

```
input = train_set(image)
input = input.unsqueeze(0)
model.eval()
output = model(input)
```

More details can be found here [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/am-getting-error-trying-to-predict-on-a-single-image-cnn-pytorch/113001)

Answer (score 0):

Plz uncomment this line `#input_var = input_var.view(1, 3, 32,32)` so that your input dimension is 4.
I assume that your no. of input channels are 3 if its one then use `input_var = input_var.view(1, 1, 32,32)` if gray scale

Comment: Thank you, but i got this error when i uncomment that line, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pred.py", line 135, in <module>
    data = data.view(1, 3, 32,32)
RuntimeError: shape '[1, 3, 32, 32]' is invalid for input of size 1024

Comment: i doubt that you dont have 3 channels,cau u try with `input_var = input_var.view(1, 1, 32,32)`

Comment: Have tried it, got this error: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 32, 32] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead